# SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error in Wordpress (Page sourcs)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. [sarahornejewelry](http://www.sarahornejewelry.com). The shop page was done with php and put it on the same server. When i tried to access the admin I was getting empty page. I tried various things. When I check page source code on web browser the following error was shown on the screen.

```
<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
```

I tried various things but none of them worked. When i put a demo html index page it works fine. It was working fine previously with the php pages

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the "admin" has any .htaccess file?

Comment: i think no.. Iam beginner to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working now?  I just went to yourdomain/wp-admin and saw the login page, or is there some admin login for the php script that's not part of wordpress?

Comment: yes.. for the shop page i use another admin other than wp-admin.